# Need help getting text from list item and putting in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html code and the dropdown is with a list

```
                        <div class="input-group m-bot15">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control round-input" id="textbox1">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">

                                <button tabindex="-1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>

                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" >2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>

                                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I'm trying to get it so when I click 1 it puts "1" in the  someone recommended using Javascript.

This is what I have tried so far:

`<li onmousedown="transferText(one)" id="one">1</li>`

Now add you input text and id too, for example textBox

```
<script>
function transferText(listItem) {
    document.getElementById(textBox).innerHTML = document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Edit Im trying to get it so when i click 1 it puts "1" in the input box, someone recommended using Javascript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have only presented the html code and no javascript.

Comment: Im not that good with javascript thats why I came here

Comment: This is not how this site works. You have to show you tried something and ask for guidance-help. If you are not good at javascript you can always learn.

Comment: Well I have to finish this in less than 10 mins so yeah, I tried some stuff but its mostly because I cant javascript

Comment: Ive tried
<li onmousedown="transferText(one)" id="one">1</li>
Now add you input text an id too, for example textBox
<script>
function transferText(listItem) {
 document.getElementById(textBox).innerHTML = document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML;
}
</script>

Comment: @DisplayName Please ask the question in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a', 'ul.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
            $('#textbox1').val($(this).text());
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry about formatting, couldn't get the input to accept copy/paste from sublime.

Comment: Happy to help with this!

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputGroup = $('.input-group');

// Bind a click event to all elements with the selector ".dropdown-menu a" 
// within ".input-group" to an anonymous function that will insert the text
// value into the input. 
inputGroup.on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', function(event)
{
    // event = jQuery click event
    // this = The anchor that was clicked
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the text value of the anchor and set it as the input value
    inputGroup.find('#textbox1').val($(this).text());
}
```

Comment: Why use .on() when the elements are not dynamic?

Comment: @osekmedia 1. Better memory efficiency 2. Namespaced events 3. Allows for dynamic elements 4. You can use `.off` to remove specific handlers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to wrap the method in a closure to NS it?

Comment: @osekmedia That would namespace the binding of the event, not the actual event. Check out http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/